# Spring 4.3.10, Java Config (not spring-boot), and CXF

Tags: xml, spring, servlets, cxf, jax-ws

I am working on an old Spring 3 application that consumes and provides many web services, which are provided by Axis 1. Upgrading the main app with the UI isn't an option right now so I am rewriting the services into a separate WAR using Spring 4.3.10 and Apache CXF 3.1.12. This new application has no UI at all, services only.

NOTE: I am doing this using the old-style Spring framework only (no spring-boot) and deploying the WAR to Tomcat.

I originally started the WAR using XML-only configuration and got the first service to deploy, with the CXF /services URL and /services/serviceX?wsdl URL responding as expected. Since then, I have switched to Java configuration. That’s where something odd went wrong.

I have an instance of WebApplicationInitializer starting up the application class that extends AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext. I used to have @ImportResource with references to the cxf.xml and cxf-servlet.xml files and they are mentioned during the startup process. However, the normal behavior of the CXFServlet to indicate that it is up and running by echoing its root URL (/services/* in my case) is not appearing like it used to when everything was configured in a Spring context.xml file.

As indicated here and elsewhere, I added the CXF servlet to the initializer:

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = null;
try {
    dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("cxf", new CXFServlet());
    dispatcher.addMapping("/services");
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    LOGGER.info("CXF Servlet successfully registered.");
} catch(Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error("There was a problem registering the CXF servlet:");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I get the info message that the servlet is registered, but in the console log, the message regarding the root path never appears. I added the appContext.refresh() method as well, and I see that message in the log.
Other messages do appear showing that some part of the bus is running:

```
DEBUG  [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] Server is starting.
```

Interestingly enough, the other @Configuration bean with the @Bean Endpoints are "published" without issue:

```
INFO   [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] Setting the server's publish address to be /testService
```

But still, without the root /services URL active, one cannot reach the service or its WSDL.

Another odd thing I noticed is that though the cfx-servlet.xml file is in cxf-rt-transports-http-x.y.z.jar/meta-inf/cxf folder as expected, short of the typical Spring XML header, the file is devoid of ANY bean declarations, unlike the cxf.xml file. I checked two versions back and the situation is the same. So, why include an empty file?

I’ve given up on the Java configuration and restored the XML files but the same behavior remains.

I suspect it is something trivial, but I’m at a loss. The web.xml follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1" metadata-complete="false"
>
    <display-name>SOS HAVA Web Service</display-name>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
 </web-app>
```